# Android studio Emulator Not powering

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

My Android studio Emulator is not coming on.
I've followed all the guides here on stackoverflow, checked Google but to no avail.
My processor is AMD.
Are there specific settings for AMD systems?

I tried Installing a lower version of Android studio like version 5.1 and it worked but google play services keep stopping and it crash anytime I install flutter App on it.

Comment: run `flutter --doctor` command in  terminal

Comment: I've done that, everything is fine

Comment: You should provide info about OS version (Windows/Linux), which AMD CPU and RAM / Hard drive space available. You may just want to confirm you read/followed: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Comment: @MorrisonChang AMD Radeon HD 6480G. 8GB RAM 320GB HDD